# Hide social buttons until fully loaded from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i show buttons untill they are fully loaded from external source. Before loading the buttons there is a gif preloader which indicates that loading is in progress. The code i posted is working to show buttons but it loads the one by one and not all at the same time.

My code is:

```
<div class="social-holder">
        <div class="social-buttons-holder">

        </div>
</div>
```

When user hovers over the div with class "social-holder" buttons will be loaded from external page named "social".

```
$('.social-holder').hover(function(){
    if($(".social-buttons").length > 0){
        $('.social-buttons-holder').show();
    } 
    else {
        $('.social-buttons-holder').addClass('preloader');
        $('.social-buttons-holder').load('/social', function() {
            $('.social-buttons-holder').removeClass('preloader');
        });
    }
}, function(){
    $('.social-buttons-holder').hide();
});
```

Structure of external page is:

```
<div class="social-buttons">
    <div class="social-button">

    </div>
    <div class="social-button">

    </div>
    <div class="social-button">

    </div>
</div>
```

Each div with class "social-button" contains standard code for social buttons so i wont post it here.
So, when user hovers over the div with class "social-holder", div with class "social-buttons" will be loaded inside of the div with class "social-buttons-holder". If social buttons are not already loaded a class "preloader" is added to the div which show a preloader gif image. When Jquery load loads external content, "preloader" class is removed, but buttons load one by one in their iframes, and i want them to load at the same time, because preloader should hide their loading process

Comment: Maybe the images for the buttons are being downloaded every time and thats why the delay is noticeable. (the images should be cashed). Another thing to try is to delay the line where you remove 'preloader'  class

Comment: Maybe if the images are cashed it will show them, but it will still load count boxes and that is nto what i want. If i delay the preloader class remove, it will still show preloader and start loading buttons so they will both be visible.

Comment: @user619656: **Cached** not cashed!